# JavaScript setInterval calling form.submit

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need submit my form based on the time out of the timer. It is not calling form submit. Please suggest me

I am calling the starttimer in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var duration = 60*20;
    display = $('#timer');
    startTimer(duration, display);

    $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
    return this
             .attr('unselectable', 'on')
             .css('user-select', 'none')
             .on('selectstart', false);
    };

    $("#question_container").disableSelection();
});

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () 
    {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            $("#questionform").submit();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
setInterval ( "autosubmit()", 5000000 );
function autosubmit()
{
document.theFormName.submit;
}
```

Comment: What is `autosubmit`? Where is its definition?

Comment: I have added the autosubmit code

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors. Timer is running in negative

Comment: @JameerBasha — The timer shouldn't be running at all. You never call `startTimer`. The only thing here that will submit the form is autosubmit (because it gets called) but that has no visible timer.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the startTimer call. I am calling it in document.ready

Answer (score 2):

`document.theFormName.submit;` doesn't do anything. It just accessing a function and then ignores it.

If you want to call it, then you actually have to call it:

```
document.theFormName.submit();
```

Comment: i have modified, but the form is not submitted

Comment: Are you waiting the hour and a half (5000000ms) you set the timer for?

Comment: I am using 3 seconds for testing in the var duration = 1*3;

Comment: Should I change that 5000000ms?

Comment: @JameerBasha — You haven't set `var duration` at all, at least not in the code in the question. If you are asking a question about some different code, you should include that code. You should read http://sscce.org/

Comment: HTML is for an online quiz

Answer (score -1):

Just change

```
setInterval ( "autosubmit()", 5000000 );
```

to

```
setInterval ( autosubmit, 5000000 );
```

> Here is more details
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Passing a function instead of a string to be evaluated, but won't make a jot of difference (unless `autosubmit` isn't a global, but there is no sign of that)